# Mosaicflow append list with new items with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, grid, mosaic

I'm using mosaicflow to list my items but there are a lots of them so i want to display only the first 20 item and after a button click show the next 20 below the first 20 and so on.

For this i use an ajax call its working perfectly, so it shows the next 20 items but then the mosaicflow layout breaks...

Has anybody an idea how i can solve this issue?

I tried to use the mosaicflow add event, but then it adds the next 20 items to the smallest column...

I also tried to append the data to the mosaicflow container but this wasn't good neither...

The html looks like this (2 columns):

```
    <div class="mosaicflow">
        <div class="mosaicflow__column">
            <div class="mosaicflow__item">
                // item details
            </div>
            <div class="mosaicflow__item">
                // item details
            </div>
            // more mosaicflow__item divs
        </div>
        <div class="mosaicflow__column">
            <div class="mosaicflow__item">
                // item details
            </div>
            <div class="mosaicflow__item">
                // item details
            </div>
            // more mosaicflow__item divs
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the ajax success i append the data i get from the script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
    //...
    success:function(data) {
    $('.mosaicflow').append(data);
    }
});
```

I get the data through ajax from the php script in this format:

```
<div class="mosaicflow__item">
    // item details
</div>
```

Update, here is the full html and ajax code:

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$categoryName = 'Category';
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_name = '$categoryName' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");

$query->execute();
$items = $query->fetchAll();
$item_id = '';
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {; ?>
    <div class="mosaicflow myContainer">                
    <?php
    foreach($items as $item) { ?>
            <div class="mosaicflow__item">
                <h3><?php echo $item['name'] ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo summary($item['text']); ?></p>
                <div class="ButtonHolder">
                    <a href="link.html" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle;"><span>Link </span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        $item_id = $item['id'];
     } ?>
    <button name="btn_more" id="btn_more" data-item="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="btn btn-success form-control" >more</button>
<?php
}
else  {
    echo "<p>There are no items!</p>";
}
?>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mosaicflow.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#btn_more', function(){
            var last_item_id = $(this).data("item");
            $('#btn-more').html("loading...");
            $.ajax({
                url: "load_items.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {last_item_id:last_item_id,categoryname:"<?php echo $categoryName; ?>"},
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if (data != '') {
                        $('#btn_more').remove();

                        // Init mosaicflow
                        var container = $('.myContainer').mosaicflow();

                        // Create new html node and append to smallest column
                        var elm = $(data);
                        container.mosaicflow('add', elm);
                        //$('.mosaicflow').append(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#btn_more').html("No Data");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ajax (load_items.php):

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$output = '';
$item_id = '';
$lastItemId = $_POST['last_item_id'];
$categoryName = $_POST['categoryname'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_name = '$categoryName' AND id < $lastItemId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$query->execute();
$items = $query->fetchAll();
$items_num = $query->rowCount();
if($items_num > 0) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item_id = $item['id'];
        $output .= '<div class="mosaicflow__item">';
        $output .= '<h3>' . $item['name'] . '</h3>';
        $output .= '<p>' . $item['text'] . '</p>';
        $output .= '<div class="ButtonHolder">';
        $output .= '<a href="link.html" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle;"><span>Link </span></a>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
    $output .= '<button name="btn_more" id="btn_more" data-item="' . $item_id . '" class="btn btn-success form-control" >more</button>';
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated jQuery ajax call

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
    //...
    success:function(data) {
    data = $('<div />').append(data).find('.mosaicflow__item').html();  
    $('.mosaicflow .mosaicflow__item').append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but its not working in my case it adds only 1 item to the list and the layout also breaks... :(

Comment: Peter, I have updated code... please try and let me know if its not working

Comment: I tried it now it adds one item to every existing item, so it's also not working correctly
I've updated the html structure because the js makes columns from the items and for this it adds a div named mosaicflow__column...

Comment: Can you please let me know that whatever response you got through ajax request should create new column or it should be append existing column ?

Comment: I've updated my post again with the html and ajax file, hope it'll be more clear.
It should append the existing columns